# Varying types in the second argument for controller function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular and as I look at the examples, I see that sometimes the `locals` argument to the `controller` function is sometimes just a function and other times it's an array.

```
angular.module('contentful').controller(
    'FormWidgetsController',
    ['$scope', "$injector", function($scope, $injector){ ... }]);
```

vs.

```
myModule.controller("GroupController", function GroupController($scope){
  ...
});
```

These are just examples I found in one example. Looking at the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller), it just says that they're injection locals for Controller with not a lot of context. Googling that doesn't bring up anything that makes sense to someone starting off like me.

Can anyone explain the difference between the two and what each implementation does?

Answer (score 0):

The different is when you minify your angular app

```
angular.module('contentful').controller(
    'FormWidgetsController',
    ['$scope', "$injector", function($scope, $injector){ ... }]);
```

will become

```
angular.module('contentful').controller(
    'FormWidgetsController',
    ['$scope', "$injector", function(a, b){ ... }]);
```

in this case angular still know what dependencies you are requiring and in which order they are injected
if you don't use array for exploring your dependencies

```
myModule.controller("GroupController", function GroupController($scope){
  ...
});
```

and when it will minify

```
 myModule.controller("GroupController", function GroupController(a){
      ...
    });
```

now angular donn't now what a is and it will give you error.

Comment: So you're saying if I don't minify my functions, then code like `myModule.controller("GroupController", function GroupController($scope, dep1, dep2){...});` will work fine?

Comment: yes if you don't want to minify you can just skip array for dependencies, there is a plugin also if you don't want to use array the plugin will do it for you when you minify.